# Llamada a Case When (sintaxis)

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo el siguiente query:

```
  select ic14.cantidad_recepcionada as recepcionados
  from comex_015 ic15
  inner join comex_014 ic14 on ic15.invoice=ic14.invoice
  where ic14.codigo_producto='KO555581012EA40' and ic14.invoice !='0' 
  group by ic14.pedido
  order by ic14.pedido desc 
  limit 1
```

El cual me muestra el dato **`ic14.cantidad_recepcionada`**, dado las condiciones mencionadas,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
hasta hay todo bien..

Pero necesito agregar una nueva condición, la cual me muestre el dato **`ic14.cantidad_recepcionada`** según un registro en la tabla **`comex_015`**

Necesito que cuando su registro en **`ic15.fecha_recepcion`** **sea nulo** , no me muestre el dato que esta trayendo actualmente o lo muestre en cero.

Estaba intentando de este modo, pero el resultado que me muestra es un **INT** DE VALOR **1**, cuando debiera mostrar un decimal de (11,0) que es **`ic14.cantidad_recepcionada`** que corresponde a **90**.

```
 select ic14.cantidad_recepcionada   = 
 (case when ic15.fecha_recepcion is not null then ic14.cantidad_recepcionada
  when ic15.fecha_recepcion is null then 0
  end) as recepcionado
 from comex_015 ic15
 inner join comex_014 ic14 on ic15.invoice=ic14.invoice
 where ic14.codigo_producto='KO555581012EA40' and ic14.invoice !='0' 
 group by ic14.pedido
 order by ic14.pedido desc 
 limit 1
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: después de `THEN` debe ir directamente el valor que quieres, no una condición lógica. En este caso, debería ser `when ic15.fecha_recepcion is null then '0'`. (claro que verificaría si es correcto que uses '0' como string en vez de número)

Comment: lo edite, lo tenia como me dices tu, pero quiere que me traiga el valor. y no un 1

Comment: Esto es porque además agregaste `ic14.cantidad_recepcionada   =` previo a la expresión `CASE`, lo que no tiene mucho sentido, y hace que evalúe la condición de igualdad en `true` o `false` (0 o 1)

Comment: @Lamak exacto, y sabes como podria ser el sintaxis correcto?

Comment: ah, claro, quitando el `ic14.cantidad_recepcionada =`

Comment: pero... y la condición??? donde seria?

Comment: qué condición?, lo que quieres es el resultado de la expresión `CASE`

Comment: tu respuesta es la correcta, porque no la indicas abajo? me compila ok, muchas gracias ;)

Comment: ok, posteé esto como una respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que lo que está evaluando tu consulta es el resultado de la condición lógica `ic14.cantidad_recepcionada = CASE WHEN …`, lo que puede dar como resultado `true` o `false` (`1` o `0`).

Lo que realmente necesitas es simplemente el resultado de la expresión `CASE`:

```
 select  
 (case when ic15.fecha_recepcion is not null then ic14.cantidad_recepcionada
  when ic15.fecha_recepcion is null then 0
  end) as recepcionado
 from comex_015 ic15
 inner join comex_014 ic14 on ic15.invoice=ic14.invoice
 where ic14.codigo_producto='KO555581012EA40' and ic14.invoice !='0' 
 group by ic14.pedido
 order by ic14.pedido desc 
 limit 1
```

Comment: Gracias estimado... me estaba ahogando en un vaso de agua  ;)